# SAPUI5: Create GenericTile with icon centered

Tags: html, css, tile, sapui5

I would like to create a tile which is inherited from sap.suite.ui.commons.GenericTile and displays only an icon (centered in the middle of the tile). Due to the centering, I cannot use the standard aggregations or property as they have the icon placed at a specific position (which is on the left lower side).

I have tried the following but with no luck:

```
$.sap.declare("myAddTile");

sap.suite.ui.commons.GenericTile.extend("myAddTile", {

init: function() {
    // do something for initialization...
    sap.suite.ui.commons.GenericTile.prototype.init.call(this);
},
renderer: function(oRm, oControl) {
    var oPlusIcon = new sap.ui.core.Icon({
        src: 'sap-icon://sys-add'
    }).placeAt(oControl);
    sap.suite.ui.commons.GenericTileRenderer.render(oRm, oControl);
}
});
```

The resulting tile is empty...

Answer (score 0):

I played around a bit with the renderer and came up with this solution:

```
    rm.write("<div");
    rm.addClass("myAddTileIcon");
    rm.addClass(oControl.getSize());
    rm.writeClasses();
    rm.writeAttribute("id", oControl.getId() + "-icon");
    rm.write(">");
    rm.renderControl(new sap.ui.core.Icon({
        src: 'sap-icon://sys-add',
        size: "5rem"
    }));
    rm.write("</div>");
```

Of course, the right alignment of the icon needs to be taken care of, too:

```
.myAddTileIcon .sapUiIcon {
  font-family: SAP-icons;
  font-size: 5rem;
  line-height: inherit;
  cursor: default;
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
  padding-top: 20%;
  vertical-align: middle;
  color: grey;
}
```

If someone has a comment how to solve this in a more elegant way, please post.

Cheers